# UglifyJS - convert all .js in a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, npm, uglifyjs

I was wondering if anyone could help, I'm attempting to finish off my build process which currently transpiles es6 > es5 using babel, After that has completed I want to use uglifyJS to recursively minify all my .js files using just NPM scripts (no grunt or gulp please).

What I desire;

- Convert all .js in folder to es5
- Minify all .js files in a given folder using uglify
- Create source maps
- Copy out to a new folder

My current setup;

- Converts all .js to es5
- Minify all es5 .js files (However no sourcemaps are created, also the es5 js files are replaced as theres no support to move to another folder)

I've tried: https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-uglifyjs and https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-folder but these both seem unable to perform the build steps I need

Here is my package.json scripts section

```
   "babel": "babel js_uncompiled --out-dir js_uncompiled/es5 --source-maps  && npm run npm:uglify",
    "build": "npm run babel",
    "uglify": "recursive-uglifyjs js_uncompiled/es5"
```

You can find a link to my full package.json here : http://pastebin.com/4UHZ1SGM

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: included info from comments

So, now [uglifyjs-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-folder) has the option of passing a config file so you can run all uglify's commands, but on a whole folder (and you can transpile to ES5 using harmony - [as stated in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309942/uglifyjs-convert-all-js-in-a-folder/47478726?noredirect=1#comment83746533_47478726)).

Note this is better than doing so manually with `cat` or other shell commands, since *uglifyjs-folder* can generate a single output file (concatenated) and is simpler to use.

Run `uglifyjs-folder "%CD%" --config-file "uglify.config.json" --output "folder" -e` where the config file (in the root folder of project) contains for example (not all options needed):

`{
  "compress": true,
  "mangle": true,
  "sourceMap": {
    "base": "input/path/",
    "content": "input/sourcemap",
    "filename": "{file}.min.js",
    "includeSources": true,
    "root": "original/source/path",
    "url": "source/path"
  }
}`

Obs.: currently there is one [open issue](https://github.com/ionutvmi/uglifyjs-folder/issues/11) by myself because source-mapping is resulting in error. Once the issue is solved I will update my answer here.

UPDATE: ok, issue solved, version 1.5 released! Code above updated

Comment: Now `uglifyjs-folder` can transpile to ES5 using harmony.

Comment: Thanks @PranavSingh, updating my answer